# Substitute only changes in insert mode

Tags: vim, range

In my vimrc, I put a code to substitute automatically when leaving the insert mode, like this:

```
augroup SubstWhenLeavingInsert
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertLeave *.tex %s/a/b/ge
augroup END
```

There is no problem with this. But I seek for a more efficient way: the above autocmd always searches in the *whole* text.

Can I replace `%` with a range that indicates "where you have edit in the insert mode"?

I guess that I can do this by using markers, but I am not sure about markers. So, please tell me whether my guess is correct or not, ot how to achieve it.

Comment: You can use `'[` and `']` marks. But that will only work if you haven't used cursor movement commands in insert mode.

Comment: Since your example is too simplified (I refuse to believe you detest the letter `a` so much), it is impossible to see what methods would be best. Is there any reason you are not solving this using `:iabbrev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously changed (or yanked) text is accessible through the [`:help '[`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%5B) and [`:help ']`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27%5D) marks. It may not directly correspond to the actual change (and commands like `:w` mark the entire buffer), but as you're only looking for an optimization here, this would be fine.

```
  autocmd InsertLeave *.tex '[,']s/a/b/ge
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although this solution has been mentioned in comments, I take this first answer as the best answer.